# Test Driven development in Yii2 not working for classes

Tags: php, yii2, tdd

I am very new to TDD but I am very verse with Yii2. I want to setup a basic yii2 application using TDD. I have followed a handful of tutorials online and the one that seems to work is https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-automated-testing-with-codeception--cms-26790

It has its limitations in that, when I setup like that, there are lots of things that do not work and they are not explained in the tutorial.

Eg, I cannot use Yii2 Inherited classes such as use yii\helpers\Url;

Secondly, I will like to understand how to write test for my controller actions. I have not seen relevant information in this light.

Thirdly, I am looking for good and standard tutorials that can help implement and understand all the concepts of TDD in Yii2.

thanks

Comment: there is a thorough guide on how to write tests see here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/test-unit

Comment: Also take a look at `yii2-user`, they have great testing code:https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/tree/master/tests/codeception ,Look in `unit/userTest`

Comment: I had seen the yii2 tutorial but its very minimal and does not handle the above exceptions. the second link does not exist